# Script that exec other scripts

Tags: plsql

I want to execute this script in PL/SQL but it keeps getting error

```
set serveroutput on;
set echo on;
declare 
  v_code varchar2(250);
  v_errm varchar2(250);
begin
  @@"1.sql";
  @@"2.sql";
  @@"II_load_438865311678_Reg.sql"; 
exception
when others then
  v_code := sqlcode;
  v_errm := substr(sqlerrm, 1, 64);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR! - '||DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_STACK|| DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE);
  rollback;
end;
/
```

What is wrong with this.

> Error: ORA-06550: line 5, colunm 3: (...) ORA-06550: line 6, colunm 3:
>   (...) ORA-06550: line 7, colunm 3: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol
>   "@" when expecting one of the following: ( begin case declare end
>   exception exit for goto if loop mod    null pragma raise return select
>   update while with... and
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>   *Action:

Comment: `@` is not a SQL (or PL/SQL) command. It's a SQL\*Plus command and can only be used at the SQL\*Plus command prompt. **Not** inside PL/SQL (because that is run on the **server** not on the client)

Comment: what is the solution to correct this?

Comment: Either created stored procedures with the other scripts that can then be run by this block, or implement error handling in each of the other scripts. I would lean towards the second, unless this call structure is a firm requirement.

Comment: the other 3 files are only inserts. I only want to create a simple script just to call in a automatic form.

Answer (score 0):

You only use the PL/SQL code to show the error. That is not necessary; SQL*Plus will already show you any SQL error. Use `whenever sqlerror` to trigger the rollback.

```
whenever sqlerror continue rollback
@@"1.sql"
@@"2.sql"
@@"II_load_438865311678_Reg.sql"
```